# Division column only returns one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sapb1

I'm writing a `SQL` query to check `Gross Profit Percentage` for a group of sales items in a database.

```
SELECT T0.[itmsgrpcod], 
       T0.sell, 
       T0.cost, 
       ( T0.sell / T0.cost ) AS "GP" 
FROM   (SELECT T0.[itmsgrpcod], 
               Sum(T1.[price])      AS "Sell", 
               Sum(T1.[stockprice]) AS "Cost" 
        FROM   inv1 T1 
               LEFT OUTER JOIN oitm T0 
                            ON T1.[itemcode] = T0.[itemcode] 
        GROUP  BY T0.[itmsgrpcod]) T0
```

I'm having an odd problem in that when I have the `SELECT` statement as:

```
SELECT T0.[ItmsGrpCod], T0.Sell, T0.Cost
```

It returns 96 rows - the correct amount, with Sell and Cost data filled.

When I add the column:

```
    (T0.Sell / T0.Cost) as "GP"
```

It returns only the first row of the query, with GP calculated properly.

Comment: I need the GROUP BY, as I'm trying to figure out the total Sell and Cost of each item group, and there are hundreds of rows for each item group.

Comment: Could you try and reproduce the problem at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) exactly as you are experiencing it using small data samples?

Comment: You've just added the `sap` tag. Could you please elaborate on how it is relevant to the problem?

Comment: The database is a SAP Business One database.

Comment: Where are you running the query and obtaining the results? Is it a custom application or is it a tool like SSMS?

Comment: That did it Andriy! SAP Business One's Query system reported it as executing completely, but it was a division by zero error. If you want the rep, re-post as an answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: Thank you! To be honest, I would prefer if you posted the answer yourself. It was a relatively wild guess on my side and you used it wisely to determine the cause, so please feel free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that SAP Business One's Query Generator does not report Division by Zero. When I tried the query in SQL Server Management Studio, it provided a proper Division by Zero error, and I fixed the problem.

Complete query, for those interested:

```
SELECT T0.ItmsGrpCod,
       SUM(T1.Price) As "Sell",
       ISNULL(SUM(T1.StockPrice), 0) As "Cost",
       CASE WHEN SUM(T1.StockPrice) = 0 THEN 100 
            ELSE (SUM(T1.Price) - SUM(T1.StockPrice)) / SUM(T1.Price) * 100
       END As "GP"
FROM INV1 T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN OITM T0 ON T1.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode
GROUP BY T0.ItmsGrpCod
ORDER BY T0.ItmsGrpCod
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, I did not do much. Just made sure that Sell and Cost are converted to Decimal.

```
SELECT  T0.[ItmsGrpCod], 
        T0.Sell, 
        T0.Cost, 
        (T0.Sell / T0.Cost) as GP
FROM    (SELECT     T0.[ItmsGrpCod], 
                    CAST(SUM(T1.[Price]) AS DECIMAL(12,2)) as Sell, 
                    CAST(SUM(T1.[StockPrice]) AS DECIMAL(12,2)) as Cost
        FROM        INV1 T1 
        LEFT JOIN   OITM T0 
        ON          T1.[ItemCode] = T0.[ItemCode]
        GROUP BY    T0.[ItmsGrpCod]) T0
```

Comment: Same outcome as running query without casts.

Answer (score 0):

I think u have problem with `alias`

Try this

```
SELECT T.[ItmsGrpCod],T.Sell,T.Cost, CAST(T.Sell AS Decimal) / T.Cost As GP
FROM
    (
      SELECT T0.[ItmsGrpCod],SUM(T1.[Price]) As Sell,SUM(T1.[StockPrice]) As Cost
      FROM INV1 T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN OITM T0 ON T1.[ItemCode] = T0.[ItemCode]
      GROUP BY T0.[ItmsGrpCod]
    )T
```

**Update**

```
SELECT T.[ItmsGrpCod],T.Sell,T.Cost,T.GP
FROM
    (
      SELECT T0.[ItmsGrpCod],
             SUM(T1.[Price]) As Sell,
             SUM(T1.[StockPrice]) As Cost,
             SUM(T1.[Price]) / SUM(T1.[StockPrice]) As GP
      FROM INV1 T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN OITM T0 ON T1.[ItemCode] = T0.[ItemCode]
      GROUP BY T0.[ItmsGrpCod]
    )T
```

Comment: I thought of that as well, and already tried changing the outer queries alias to a different one. Still the same result, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried with updated query like `CAST(T.Sell AS Decimal) / T.Cost As GP` @BenHarris

Comment: Yep - still the same outcome, only one row returned.

Comment: @BenHarris Have you duble checked that `SELECT T0.[ItmsGrpCod], T0.Sell, T0.Cost` Without GP has returned 96 rows?

Comment: Yes - I can confirm it returns all rows.

Comment: @BenHarris Can you check my new updated query and let me know.

Comment: Still returned only one row.

Comment: @BenHarris Can you please provide me a sample fiddle

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56360/1

Works fine in SQLFiddle..doesn't work for the real DB though..

Comment: You have mentioned  `sql server` tag but fiddle in `mysql`.. and  you mentioned `SAP` too. Please say your exact DB... @BenHarris

Answer (score 0):

As every one in this thread even I am puzzled and intrigued. I have added some test data to see whats going on However I am unable to replicate your scenerio.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'TempINV1') > 0
    BEGIN
       DROP TABLE TempINV1
    END
IF OBJECT_ID(N'TempOITM') > 0
    BEGIN
       DROP TABLE TempOITM
    END

CREATE TABLE TempINV1 (ItemCode INT,
                   Price DECIMAL(8, 2),
                   StockPrice DECIMAL(8, 2))
CREATE TABLE TempOITM (ItemCode INT,
                   ItmsGrpCod VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO TempINV1
VALUES
(1, '3.21', '2.34'),
(2, '4.32', '3.45'),
(3, '5.43', '4.56')

INSERT INTO TempOITM
VALUES
(1, 'Product1'),
(2, 'Product2'),
(3, 'Product3')
```

**Both your sacripts(table names prefixed with Temp) outputs the same number of row items**

```
SELECT T0.[ItmsGrpCod], T0.Sell, T0.Cost, (T0.Sell / T0.Cost) as "GP"
FROM (
  SELECT T0.[ItmsGrpCod], SUM(T1.[Price]) as "Sell", SUM(T1.[StockPrice]) as "Cost"
  FROM TempINV1 T1 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TempOITM T0 
  ON T1.[ItemCode] = T0.[ItemCode]
  GROUP BY T0.[ItmsGrpCod]) T0

--Or

SELECT T0.[ItmsGrpCod], T0.Sell, T0.Cost
FROM (
  SELECT T0.[ItmsGrpCod], SUM(T1.[Price]) as "Sell", SUM(T1.[StockPrice]) as "Cost"
  FROM TempINV1 T1 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TempOITM T0 
  ON T1.[ItemCode] = T0.[ItemCode]
  GROUP BY T0.[ItmsGrpCod]) T0
```

Outputs for both queries are same (number or rows returned).

Please can you run the scripts on your machine and confirm if that is true. Also to help us better understand, it would be great if you could provide us some sample date.

**Compensate for divide by zero:**

```
SELECT T0.ItmsGrpCod,
      T0.Sell,
      T0.Cost,
      T0.Sell / CASE
              WHEN ISNULL(T0.Cost, '0') = 0 THEN T0.Sell
              ELSE T0.Cost
              END AS "GP"
FROM(SELECT T0.ItmsGrpCod,
          SUM(T1.Price)AS "Sell",
          SUM(T1.StockPrice)AS "Cost"
    FROM TempINV1 AS T1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TempOITM AS T0
        ON T1.ItemCode = T0.ItemCode
    GROUP BY T0.ItmsGrpCod)AS T0
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I figured out the problem - SAP Business One was reporting a Division By Zero error as a successful execution!

Comment: Aww that explains it. Thanks for posting your answer and findings. I would have gone crazy otherwise. I have also modified my response to compensate for division by zero error.